# What is this plant with purple berries?

Tags: species-identification

This plant was seen by a friend of mine in Virginia. What is it?
[image: ignore the caption on the photo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like beautyberry. Here is a link to a species page to judge for yourself. It's a very common cultivar and I've heard of people using it to control garden pests.

http://uswildflowers.com/detail.php?SName=Callicarpa%20americana

Here is an image of American Beautyberry from gardenknowhow. 
[image]

It is often confused with Japanese Beautyberry which has smaller berries on stalks.

Comment: Though your proposed ID may be correct, please embed an image of the plant into your response, and possibly include a bit of general information. +1 if you can do this.